# HRESULT "Class Not Registered" Implementing simple COM server DLL

Tags: c++, com, regsvr32

I'm following this sites tutorial:

http://progtutorials.tripod.com/COM.htm

Preliminary evidence: Visual Studio 2010, Windows 7 64 bit.

and I'm coding the examples in section 3. (Implementing a server DLL). I've typed out the code exactly as shown and I'm getting a "Class not registered" exception when executing this code on line 12 of the code outlined in section 4.1 (where the tutorial shows you how to access the DLL and I have followed 3.1 to the letter):

```
 hresult hr = CoGetClassObject(CLSID_Car, CLSCTX_SERVER, NULL, IID_IClassFactory, (void **) &pClassFactory);
```

I tried running:

```
 regsvr32 xyz.dll
```

with xyz.dll being the path to my dll in order to register the DLL. This resulted in an error trying to find DLLRegisterServer:

[image]

I have already run

```
 REGEDIT
 HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CarDLL.Car\CLSID = {d969084c-b758-43ea-a218-a48763167abd}
 HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{d969084c-b758-43ea-a218-a48763167abd} = CarDLL.Car
 HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{d969084c-b758-43ea-a218-a48763167abd}\InProcServer32 = C:\Users\wiocl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CarDLL\debug\CarDLL.dll
```

that I assumed put all the GUIDS I needed in the registry (The GUIDS were generated by me).

I'm assuming that a function is needed to be added to the class that allows it to be registered but I don't know how to do this and how to go about figuring it out. I'm kind of lost, as I haven't been working with COM for very long. If someone could give me a shove in the right direction that would be helpful.

Edit: Oh yes, I moved 
     #include  // contains definition of DEFINE_GUID

to the iid.h file from iid.cpp, otherwise I was getting unresolved external errors on the build.

Comment: What tool are you using to create the COM DLL?

Comment: I just coded the files dictated in the tutorial in a Win32 dll project in Visual Studio and built it. It generated a DLL file, and so that's what I'm pointing my project to.

Comment: regsvr32 calls the DllRegisterServer in the the DLL, and you are not providing that interface.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682162(v=vs.85).aspx  Also, Are you crafting all this by hand just as a learning exercise?  If not, you could eliminate a lot of this work by using existing frameworks such as ATL.

Comment: Did not know about ATL- was just told to implement something specific in COM so I decided to implement something basic first. I'll check it out.

Comment: Also, COM is a pretty out-dated technology, so I am not even sure what support is available in the newer VS tools.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - COM is *everywhere* in Windows, so yes, it's 3000% supported.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation:  you are building your COM object as a 32-bit DLL, but the registration has been performed as a 64-bit DLL.

The treatment:  open an admin privileged command window and navigate to the location of your DLL (C:\Users\wiocl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\CarDLL\debug). Once there, type:

```
c:\windows\sysWOW64\regedit <filename of .reg file whose contents are displayed above>
```

This will run the 32-bit version of REGEDIT, ensuring that the registry entries are created in the correct part of the hive.  To verify this, you should see an entry for `{d969084c-b758-43ea-a218-a48763167abd}` in HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID, **not** HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID.

`DllRegisterServer` is a method you can implement in your COM server DLL, and is required if you want to use `regsvr32` to perform the same operation you are currently using the .REG approach for.  The same caveat applies:  for a 32-bit DLL, you'll need to invoke `c:\windows\sysWOW64\regsvr32.exe`.

And Yes!  COM is still **mostly** alive and well :)  At least there is still standard support for it in VS 2012.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The 32 vs 64 bit issue would not raise the "entry point not found" error, it would be a bad image format or something like that.

Comment: clarified answer -- he is missing the DllRegisterServer method